# Excel formula to assist with filling dates in down column

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Column A contains leave dates, Column B contains clinicians.  Data was extracted from VISTA and only includes leave date for first employee listed.  Is there an easier way than copying and pasting to extend the dates in column A to include each employee?  Most likely I would be working with over 50,000 total rows ( at least to begin with), so I would prefer to avoid copying and pasting.

Here is what the data currently looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJbTX.jpg)

Here is what I would like the data to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPJXa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Select entire column with Dates
2. Press `Ctrl + g`
3. Click Special...
4. Select Blanks
5. Click OK
6. With the blank cells selected (and assuming the first blank cells is A3) put this into the formula bar: `=if(B3<>"",A2,"")`
7. Instead of pressing `Enter` to save the formula to just the first blank cell, press `Ctrl + Enter` to save it to all selected cells
8. Right click on any selected cell and change the format to Date (Screenshot below at this point)
9. Select the entire column A again, then copy and paste special as values to convert the formulas to date values that you can sort/filter on. (Let me know if you need more detail on this step)

[image: Filling Formula]

Comment: Michael, this is perfect.  It works beautifully!  If you ever get to Ann Arbor, let me know, I owe you a beverage of your choosing.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm stuck in Sydney at the moment so won't be able to make the drink sorry! It would be good if you marked the answer as correct to close the question though. (The tick symbol at the top of the answer.) Thanks!

Comment: There is a green check mark showing next to your answer now.  I tried marking your answer as useful but alas, it looks as though I have not accumulated enough reputation points yet.  Thanks again, Michael!